# Oracle auto increment - newbie so go easy please

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Hi all I am looking to create an auto increment in the following table using GUEST_ID as the column that would increment.

```
CREATE TABLE "HOTEL_BOOKINGS"."GUEST" (
    "GUEST_ID" NUMBER, 
    "LASTNAME" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
    "FIRSTNAME" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "ADDRESS" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE),
    "TOWN" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
    "PHONE" NUMBER,
    "POSTCODE" VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
    "EMAIL" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE)  
);
```

I have tried nearly everything to get this working and am at my wits end
once again sorry if this is a newbie question but I need coursework handed in tomorrow

Comment: You cant just do that in Oracle can you ?

Comment: You can't just do what in Oracle?

Comment: Which Oracle version are you using? In Oracle 12 you can simply define a default value taken from a sequence.

Comment: I am using the latest oracle doanloaded around a week ago from the website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle doesn't have an autoincrement property, but you could use a sequence and an `ON INSERT` trigger to utilize its value:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE hotel_bookings_seq 
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
NOMAXVALUE;

CREATE TRIGGER hotel_bookings_tr
BEFORE INSERT ON hotel_bookings
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SELECT hotel_bookings_seq.nextval INTO :new.guest_id FROM dual;
END;
/
```

Comment: Many thanks I will give this a try, I think I have tried omething similar but you look like you have extra rows of code in there that I did not have

Comment: Is there a way to delete already implemented sequences ?

Comment: @user2966477 If you don't need them, just drop them `DROP SEQUENCE some_sequence`

Comment: With tis code is it still necessary to add values like this  INSERT INTO GUEST(GUEST_ID,FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, PHONE, ADDRESS, TOWN, POSTCODE, EMAIL)VALUES(seq_person.nextval,'Elroy','Craddock','01497 3139773','36 Yaffingale Gate','Tadley','RG78 2AB','e.craddock@yautia.co.uk'); or can I elimante the VALUE (seq_person.nextval)

Comment: When running it (I think I have it working) and inputing values, I now get this error SQL Error: ORA-01722: invalid number, but it does not indicate where about ?

Comment: I think I have some resemblece of success, but hd to change one of my columns to varchar2, many many thaks for the help

Comment: @user2966477. If you are using one of the latest versions you can just use the [Identity column](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/gateways.121/e22508/migr_tools_feat.htm#DRDAA109)